# How do I handle exception on a service with spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, error-handling

I have the following service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @JmsListener(destination = "queue")
  public void receiveMessage(String message) throws JMSException, IOException {
    LOG.info("Got message:  " + message);
    MyObject obj = objectMapper.readValue(message, MyObject.class);
    LOG.info("Object Name " + obj.getName());
  }
}
```

If `receiveMessage` throws an error I want to log this error into a log file. How do I do this with Spring boot?

Comment: you can use try and catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @JmsListener(destination = "queue")
  public void receiveMessage(String message) throws JMSException, IOException  {
    try{
        LOG.info("Got message:  " + message);
        MyObject obj = objectMapper.readValue(message, MyObject.class);
        LOG.info("Object Name " + obj.getName());
    }catch (JMSException |  IOException e){
      LOG.error(e.getMesage(),e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its already catches JMS and IO Exception then why you declare throws JMSException, IOException in a method signature.

Comment: It catches the exception, logs, and throws. Rethrowing the exception is to prevent cascading effect means if there is an issue and without throwing the exception call will move to the next method in the chain, which should not be desirable sometime. To prevent that rethrowing the exception.

Comment: if you think otherwise you can change the method signature and don't rethrow